# Canvas and InputMap

Tags: java, canvas, jpanel, awt, keylistener

I'm building a 2d game in Java and I decided to use Canvas on which I would display the images relevant to the current frame. I'm using Canvas because I've heard it is more efficient in terms of time than JPanel. Is it true?

Also, I would like to add some input to the game through **key bindings** since key listeners could cause focus issues and are lower level construct: [keylistener not working after clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074316/keylistener-not-working-after-clicking-button) (see answer).
Is there a way to use key bindings with a Canvas? Or I would simply use KeyListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can't add KeyBindings to awt.Canvas, there isn't method implemented in API
- you can to add only KeyListener
- change your decision and to use JPanel/JComponent

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is JPanel as efficient as Canvas in terms of time (I know JPanel is lightweight component while Canvas isn't so I'm not asking about memory)

Comment: there I can't see difference, in the case that there is/are some (J)Component(s) or Java2D,