# Java JFrame BufferStrategy vs Canvas BufferStrategy

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, awt

As can be seen from the [`Canvas`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) class and the [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class, the methods related to `BufferStrategy` (of the `Canvas` and of the `JFrame`) don't come from the same parent.
The `createBufferStrategy` of JFrame for example, is inherited by `Window`, which is not a parent of `Canvas`, while `Canvas` implements its own. Actually, their last common ancestor is `Component` which doesn't have this method.

So I'm wondering whether the functionality of the two is the same, and whether my program will behave the same when replacing the `createBufferStrategy`/`getBufferStrategy` of the `Canvas` with the `createBufferStrategy`/`getBufferStrategy` of the `Window`.

I've decided to do this "replace move" because I read yesterday `JPanel` is no slower than `Canvas` here: **[Canvas and InputMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211932/canvas-and-inputmap)**.

So I basically want to add `JPanel` instead of `Canvas` now.
When I started coding, my first choice was `Canvas` because of this:
 *[tutorial on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfyE7iQg9SY)*. So you can see more or less my code there, even though I've done a few changes, as they are not related to this topic.

Comment: If you're using a JFrame, draw on a JPanel.  The AWT comparison would be between a Frame and a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, Canvas and Window inherited the `createBufferStrategy()` and `getBufferStrategy()` methods from Component, but now oracle has change it because they just wanted Window and Canvas classes(and their subclasses) have these methods, not the other COmponent subclasses.

So yes, there are not differences between the `createBufferStrategy()` and `getBufferStrategy()` methods from Canvas and Window, and you can use either `CanvasObject.getBufferStrategy()` and `JFrameObject.getBufferStrategy()`

Answer (score 0):

First things first in Java when you are creating a GUI it is usually recommended to use swing instead of AWT. To answer your question, no creating a buffer strategy for a JFrame or a JPanel will not function the way you want it to I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work at all actually. All swing components are already double buffered so it is unnecessary to create a bufferstrategy. I have skimmed the videos you provided in that link and I can see where you are going with this. I recommend looking at the first answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327244/how-to-paint-multiple-objects-of-same-class-onto-one-jpanel) page that for some reason is not the excepted answer but it extremely helpful.