# KeyListener on a disabled button

Tags: java, jbutton, keylistener

I have a series of buttons in my code. I have added key listeners to individual buttons to listen to keys, so that when user presses RIGHT, LEFT,UP DOWN, I can transfer focus to the next button.

Note: I know that TAB can be used

now everything works really great! but when the focus is at a disabled button. I am not able to listen to it.

Any suggestions, as to how I can go around the problem?

Please pardon me before hand for amateur coding style!

addEntry.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                       if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)   
                            {calPeriod.setFocusable(true);
            calPeriod.grabFocus();
            }if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                getTime.setFocusable(true);
                getTime.grabFocus();
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                {
                    genChart.setFocusable(true);
                    genChart.grabFocus();
                }           

            }


    });
```

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8074326/4852017) could be helpful

Comment: I will try using key bindings too... Will update when done!

Comment: I tried with key binding... it gives me same result as before ... it seems as though on setting setEnabled to false state... all listeners on that button are disabled.