# why the key pressed does not trigger any event?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, window, actionlistener

Following is a program that displays a black screen with a messgage *ALARM !* :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class displayFullScreen extends Window {
    private JLabel alarmMessage = new JLabel("Alarm !");

    public displayFullScreen() {
        super(new JFrame());
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        alarmMessage.setFont(new Font("Cambria",Font.BOLD,100));
        alarmMessage.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
        add(alarmMessage);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
        setBackground(Color.black);

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                escapeHandler(ke);
           } 
        });
    }

    public void escapeHandler(KeyEvent ke) {
        if(ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_ESCAPE) {
            System.out.println("escaped !");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not escaped !");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new displayFullScreen().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have set a key handler in this program . The handler catches the keys pressed when the focus is on window.
When the escape key will be pressed `escaped !` should be displayed otherwise `!escaped`.
But nothing gets displayed,when i press a key. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want a window but you have two problems:

1. You should extend JWindow, not Window when using a Swing application
2. Even extending JWindow won't work because a JWindow won't receive KeyEvent unless it is parent JFrame is visible.

So you should be using a JFrame. If you don't want the title bar and borders, then you can use an undecorated JFrame.

Also, you should NOT be using a KeyListener because even on a JFrame key events are only dispatched to the focused component. Instead you should be using [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). In this case it seems you should be adding the binding to the root pane of the frame.

Comment: An alternative would be to add the listener to each component, the solution given to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286727/java-keylistener-for-jframe-is-being-unresponsive

Comment: @ChipMcCormick, no that is not a good solution. As I already stated a KeyListener should NOT be used. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Extend JFrame instead and get rid of the super call.

Comment: Why should i, when i want window ? I hope you understand the difference

Comment: I'm guessing you could get that to work for the window. You'd just need to add the listener to the frame passed to the super constructor