# why doesn't the frame close when i press the escape key?

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe, actionlistener

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class displayFullScreen extends JFrame {
        private JLabel alarmMessage = new JLabel("Alarm !");
        private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        public displayFullScreen() {
            setUndecorated(true);
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            alarmMessage.setText("Alarm !");
            alarmMessage.setFont(new Font("Cambria",Font.BOLD,100));
            alarmMessage.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            panel.add(alarmMessage);
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
            panel.setBackground(Color.black);
            add(panel);

            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
               public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {  // handler
        if(ke.getKeyCode() == ke.VK_ESCAPE) {
                       System.out.println("escaped ?");
                       setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // trying to close
                    } else {
                       System.out.println("not escaped");
                     }
              } 
           });
        }          

        public static void main(String args[]) {
    new displayFullScreen().setVisible(true);
    }
```

}

I have set a listener for the keys .When ever i press `ESC` key why doesn't the frame close ?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: dont use KeyListeners, instead use KeyBindings. Even using the correct way of closing the frame, this will stop working the moment you add a focusable component

Comment: Why are you still using a KeyListener??? In your last posting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454043/why-the-key-pressed-does-not-trigger-any-event) you where told the proper solution is to use Key Bindings!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The invocation  of `setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`  does not close the frame, it will define the behaviour when the windows decoration [X] close button is pressed (Which you have disabled for full screen).
You could replace this with `setVisible(false);` or exit your programm.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: You can also dispatch a `WINDOW_CLOSING` event, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5540802/230513).

Answer (score 9):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public abstract class EscapableFrame extends JFrame
{
    public EscapableFrame()
    {
        // on ESC key close frame
        getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "Cancel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        getRootPane().getActionMap().put("Cancel", new AbstractAction()
        { 

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
                //framename.setVisible(false);
            }
       });

   }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `dispose()` method.

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {  // handler
    if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
      System.out.println("escaped ?");
      displayFullScreen.this.dispose();
      } 
     else {
      System.out.println("not escaped");
      }
     } 
});
```

Comment: yep, i remember that i had some problems whith "setVisible(flase);" method, but dispose() works fine

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing your your frame at esc key. You are just setting its default close operation so you must write

```
System.exit(0);
```

or

```
dispose();
```

instead of

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

---

If you don't want to exit the application then use `setVisible(false)`.

---

Tip:

`VK_ESCAPE` is static filed of `KeyEvent` class so instead of `ke.VK_ESCAPE` you can write `KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE`.

Comment: no i don't want to exit the JVM. This page is linked with other windows.