# Where to addKeyListener in order to 'always' be listening

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I need a `keylistener` to be always 'listening' for the escape key to be pressed, to then exit the program.

I have tried typing     `addKeyListener(this);` in my main constructor (the one with the panel being drawn in) and have used

```
public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e)

{
      int code = e.getKeyCode();
      if(code == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
      {
           System.exit( 0 );
      }


}
```

I get no errors, but pressing the escape key doesn't seem to do anything, any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286727/java-keylistener-for-jframe-is-being-unresponsive

Comment: Don't use KeyListener, but rather use KeyBindings. This will avoid the kind of issues you are describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`Top-Level Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) by default never receiving `KeyEvent` from [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), by default, but is possible with a few code lines, wrong idea, wrong listener
- [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) by defaul react to `KeyEvent`, but only in the case that `isFocusable`, is `FocusOwner`,  wrong idea, wrong listener, (for example) because you needed to move `Focus` from `JTextField` to `JPanel` programatically, wrong idea
- add [`KeyBindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to `JFrame`/ `JDialog` / `JWindow`, accesible by default for `Swing JComponent`, not for `AWT Components`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I set the focus to the panel using requestFocusInWindow(); and assigned the keylistner to the panel directly

Comment: hmmmm see clear, simple, [but great workaround Escape Key and Dialog](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/escape-key-and-dialog/) by @camickr

Answer (score 1):

You can use the InputMap/ActionMap mechanism :

```
    Object escapeActionKey = new Object();
    pnl.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), escapeActionKey);
    pnl.getActionMap().put(escapeActionKey, new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("escape 1");
        }
    });
```

`JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` means that this keystroke is available when the `pnl` component is in the focused window.

Or you can also add a global AWTEventListener listener :

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if(event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                KeyEvent kEvent = (KeyEvent) event;
                boolean isEsc = (kEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
                if(isEsc) {
                    System.err.println("escape 2");
                }
            }
        }
    }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swing there is a top layer panel : the GlassPane which allow to handle event at top level (to avoid other widget to comsume the event)

Comment: How could I add a listener to the GlassPane? I'm getting 'cannot find symbol'

Comment: This has the capacity to consume all the events, meaning none of the other components can react to them