# How to release KeyEvents events after KeyEventDispatcher fires?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, keyboard-events

I'm trying to implement a KeyListener for a JFrame form in java.  So far, I used the [code suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379517/906428)

and got a fairly good result, but when the event fires (when any of the desired keys is pressed), it seems that not only do I get the last key pressed, but as the occurrences continue, I get 2, 3, etc, values of keys (which can be seen by the ammount of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() displayed).

How can I limit the evaluation of the event to JUST the last key pressed? or, how can I "clear" the key pressed array each time the event fires?

Here is the full code for my form:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyEventPostProcessor;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;


public class frmMain extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    char optionselected;
    String other;
    private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) { optionselected = e.getKeyChar(); }
            other = String.valueOf(optionselected).toUpperCase();
            switch (other) {
                case "C": JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 1"); break;
                case "T": JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 2"); break;
                case "D": JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 3"); break;
                case "N": JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 4"); break;
                case "O": JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 5"); break;
                case "S": JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 6"); break;
                default: break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }    
    /**
     * Creates new form frmMain
     */
    public frmMain() {
        initComponents();
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());     
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        mbarMenu = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        mnuConta = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        mnuTeso = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        mnuDiezmo = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        mnuNomi = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        mnuCole = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        mnuExit = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
        setResizable(false);

        jInternalFrame1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 607));
        jInternalFrame1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 607));
        jInternalFrame1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 607));
        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        mnuConta.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/books_noun_9566_cc.png"))); // NOI18N
        mnuConta.setText("[C] = Option 1");
        mnuConta.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        mbarMenu.add(mnuConta);

        mnuTeso.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/money_noun_197480_cc.png"))); // NOI18N
        mnuTeso.setText("[T] = Option 2");
        mnuTeso.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        mbarMenu.add(mnuTeso);

        mnuDiezmo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/diezmador_noun_247665_cc.png"))); // NOI18N
        mnuDiezmo.setText("[D] = Option 3");
        mnuDiezmo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        mbarMenu.add(mnuDiezmo);

        mnuNomi.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/payroll_noun_233106_cc.png"))); // NOI18N
        mnuNomi.setText("[N] = Option 4");
        mnuNomi.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        mbarMenu.add(mnuNomi);

        mnuCole.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/school_noun_147545_cc.png"))); // NOI18N
        mnuCole.setText("[O] = Option 5");
        mnuCole.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        mbarMenu.add(mnuCole);

        mnuExit.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/logout_noun_14841_cc.png"))); // NOI18N
        mnuExit.setText("[S] = Option 6");
        mnuExit.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        mnuExit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                mnuExitMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        mbarMenu.add(mnuExit);

        jInternalFrame1.setJMenuBar(mbarMenu);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 989, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 539, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void mnuExitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        this.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmMain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmMain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmMain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frmMain.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new frmMain().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void salida(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar mbarMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenu mnuCole;
    private javax.swing.JMenu mnuConta;
    private javax.swing.JMenu mnuDiezmo;
    private javax.swing.JMenu mnuExit;
    private javax.swing.JMenu mnuNomi;
    private javax.swing.JMenu mnuTeso;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The `MyDispatcher` class implements the KeyListener, and is supposed to raise a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() only once for each time a desired key is pressed.

Thank you in advance for any guidance on the subject.

Comment: Short answer is, use the Key Bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Key Bindings instead of Key Listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is, you are getting both a key pressed and key released event, but you are only changing `optionselected` on key release.

So:

- Pressing <kbd>C</kbd>, on `keyPressed`, `optionSelected` is `null`, `other` will be `null`, on `keyReleased`, `optionSelected` becomes `C`, show dialog
- Pressing <kbd>T</kbd>, on `keyPressed` `optionselected` is (still) `C`, show dialog, on `keyReleased` `optionselected` becomes `T`, show dialog

Instead, you should be processing only the `keyReleased` event

```
private class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
            optionselected = e.getKeyChar();
            other = String.valueOf(optionselected).toUpperCase();
            switch (other) {
                case "C":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 1");
                    break;
                case "T":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 2");
                    break;
                case "D":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 3");
                    break;
                case "N":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 4");
                    break;
                case "O":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 5");
                    break;
                case "S":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 6");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Having said all that, `KeyEventDispatcher` is very, very low level, a better solution might be to use the key bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation for `dispatchKeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html):

> Return `true` if the KeyboardFocusManager should take no further
>   action with regard to the KeyEvent; `false` otherwise

Also you can directly consume the event in your `dispatchKeyEvent` implementation when no further processing of the event is required.

```
e.consume();
```

Suggestion of @MadProgrammer is also important. Using of global event processing possibilities is the last choice.

Comment: Given the fact that the OP is changing the state of the `optionselected` ONLY when on `KEY_RELESED`, consuming the event or even changing the return value will have little effect, as the dialog is been shown based on the `optionselected` state