# Run code when pressing on the [x]

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, virtual-machine

I am making a distributed concurrent game online using Java and Swing. I want to remove the player's icon from the game zone when the user press the [x] to close the window. How can i say to the VM to execute a function before terminating the process?

Comment: Any attempts? Any code you can provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `JFrame`, set its default close operation do `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` and add a `WindowListener` to react on `windowClosing`.

This method can do what ever is needed and then just `dispose` the window to actually close it.

Note: this can also be used to ask the user if she/he really wants to exit...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a JFrame, I think you should better write your own KeyEventDispatcher like described in that post: [Unresponsive KeyListener for JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286727/unresponsive-keylistener-for-jframe)
If you're just adding a KeyListener to a JFrame and you have selectable components placed on it, you have to add the listener to all these components too, presumably recursively.

You can then detect when somebody presses x and then call the dispose function of the JFrame. If you're also adding a WindowListener to your JFrame, you can put some code in the windowClosing method that is called before the frame closes.