# JavaFX .setOnKeyPressed() works only once after starting a game

Tags: java, javafx

I have to code a simple game for my class, but I have a problem with moving my 'character'. It works perfectly fine, but only for the first time I press one of the arrow keys. After that it doesn't respond anymore. Please tell me how to make it work every time I press the key. Thanks!

```
public void startGame()
{
    gRow = 1;
    gCol = 1;
    setUpLabels();

    gp.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            switch(keyEvent.getCode()){
            case DOWN:
            {
                labels[gRow + 1][gCol].getStyleClass().add("guard");
                labels[gRow + 1][gCol].setText("G");
                gRow++;
            }
            break;

            case UP:
            {
                labels[gRow - 1][gCol].getStyleClass().add("guard");
                labels[gRow - 1][gCol].setText("G");
                gRow--;
            }
            break;
            case RIGHT:
            {
                labels[gRow][gCol+1].getStyleClass().add("guard");
                labels[gRow][gCol+1].setText("G");
                gCol++;
            }
            break;
            case LEFT: 
            {
                labels[gRow][gCol-1].getStyleClass().add("guard");
                labels[gRow][gCol-1].setText("G");
                gCol--;
            }
            break;
            }
        }

    });
    gp.requestFocus();
```

This is my startGame() method in GUI class, where my setOnKeyPressed() method is placed.

Answer (score 0):

What is gp? You add your listener only the 'gp' component. Maybe this component lost the focus after some actions. You can add your own KeyEventDispatcher to KeyboardFocusManager like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379517/6405072