# JTextField order of numbers left to right

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I am trying to make calculator and i have an issue with JTextField. When I click numbers(JButtons) like 1,2,3,4,5 , they appears on JTextField like 54321. So, how can i change this to show 12345 instead of 54321?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton clickedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();


    String displayValue = parent.getDisplayValue();

    String clickedBtnValue = clickedButton.getText();

    parent.setDisplayValue(clickedBtnValue + displayValue);
```

---

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
    textField = new JTextField(30);
    textField.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    textField.setBounds(10, 11, 152, 32);
    textField.setColumns(1);
    textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    textField.addActionListener(eng);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 184, 312);

    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you really think about this BEFORE you asked the question?

You are in control of your code so you should understand what your code is doing:

```
parent.setDisplayValue(clickedBtnValue + displayValue);
```

The code is doing exactly what you tell it to do - the button text is appended before the existing text.

If you don't like it displayed that way then you can try:

```
parent.setDisplayValue(displayValue + clickedBtnValue);
```

If you want a better solution, you can use the `replaceSelection(...)` method as demonstrated in: [How to add a shortcut key for a jbutton in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739623/how-to-add-a-shortcut-key-for-a-jbutton-in-java/33739732#33739732)

Comment: @Sinclair, yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Oh. I am an one month begginer so i sufferd for three days before I asked. Thank you for you answer! :)