# How to design multiple buttons at once

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Is there anyway to design multiple buttons at once? I have 9 buttons and I don't wanna design it 1 by 1. Is there anyway to do this? I am good even the can be the same. And also what I wanna do is, in my JPanel, is there anyway to add multiple buttons at once? like panel.add(b1,b2,b3,...)

I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
JButton btn = null;
switch (i) {
case 0:
btn = b1;
break;
case 1:
btn = b2;
}
//And btn is up to b9 and i is up to 8
btn.setBackground(Color.black);
btn.setBorderPainted(false);

}
```

Comment: Are you using a graphical GUI designer, or just writing code?  And sorry, no, there's no `add` method that takes multiple arguments.

Comment: did you try using a loop?

Comment: Yes I did let me show you what I did, let me edit it.

Comment: Not sure why you have a switch case. Just 1) create the button 2) set the properties and 3) add the button to your panel. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33739732/131872 for a working example of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As per the document

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html

There is no such method available

if you want such method, then you need to create a custom class extending JPanel