# How do I bind a key to a JButton?

Tags: java, key-bindings, action-mapping

I have a simple `JButton` linked to an `actionPerformed` method. Now I want to bind a key to the button so that when i press this key on the keyboard it performs the same action it would perform by pressing the button with the mouse.

I found out this code is working but as you can see I have to write twice the code to perform when key is pressed or button is pressed.

Is there a way to avoid this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;


public class provakey implements ActionListener{

    private JButton bStart;                                         
    
    //Costruttore
    public provakey() throws IOException{
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        bStart = new JButton("Avvia");
        bStart.addActionListener(this);
        bStart.setActionCommand("start");
        bStart.setBounds(140,10,150,40);

        AbstractAction buttonPressed = new AbstractAction() {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (bStart.isEnabled()){

                System.out.println("pressed");
                }
            }
        };
        bStart.getActionMap().put("start", buttonPressed);
        bStart.getInputMap(javax.swing.JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).
                put(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_A,0), "start");

        buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
        buttonPanel.setBounds(0,240,600,60);
        buttonPanel.add(bStart);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(buttonPanel);
        frame.setTitle("Prova");
        frame.setSize(600, 350);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("start".equals(e.getActionCommand())) { 
            buttonPressed();
        }
    }

    public void buttonPressed(){
        System.out.println("pressed");
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
        provakey p = new provakey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m unsure what you’re asking … just call `buttonPressed` in your key press handler.

Comment: or call `bStart.doClick()` within the AbstractAction. No need to check if button is enabled if you do this.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph, Hovercraft Full Of Eels  this partially solved my problem..Is it mandatory to write the "AbstractAction" ? cant i just relay on the "actionPerformed" method?
and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to write twice the code to perform when key is pressed or button is pressed.

An `Action` is an `ActionListener`.

So, you can add an Action to the button, so the same Action will be executed whether you click on the button or use the key binding:

```
//bStart.addActionListener(this);
bStart.addActionListener( buttonPressed );
```

There is no need to set the action command since you now have a unique class for your "Start" processing that is not shared by other buttons in your class.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33739732/131872 for a working example.