# How do I add ActionListener to multiple buttons created in a for loop?

Tags: java, swing

This is a difficult ask, but how do I add an `ActionListener` to multiple buttons that I have created in a for loop?

Here's my code so far:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Loop extends JFrame {

    public Loop() {
        this.setSize(700, 300);
        this.setLocation(400, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,6));
        
        JButton[] jButton = new JButton[6];
        String string[] = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six"};
        
        this.add(jpanel);
        int j=0;
        for(int i =0; i<jButton.length;i++) {
            while(j < 6) {
            jButton[i]= new JButton();
            jButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            jButton[i].setText(string[j++]);
            
            jpanel.add(jButton[i]);
            jButton[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Works");
                }
            });
            }
        }   
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loop myLoop = new Loop();
        myLoop.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(It seems from the code that to add the `ActionListener`  in a `for` loop gives all the buttons the same action. Problem is I want the actions to be different for each button).

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All of your action listeners do the same thing and print "works". What do you want each button to do? If you're going to use a loop, you have to choose the actions based on a loop.

Comment: *Problem is I want the actions to be different for each button* - If the Action is different, the you should create a separate ActionListener for each button. You should NOT use  `switch` logic in an ActionListener. However, if the Action is similar but not exact, then you can create a common listener to be shared by all buttons. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739623/how-to-add-a-shortcut-key-for-a-jbutton-in-java/33739732#33739732 for an example of this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list or array of `ActionListener`'s and pass it to the constructor, for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Loop extends JFrame {

    public Loop(java.util.List<ActionListener> listeners) {

        this.setSize(700, 300);
        this.setLocation(400, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6));

        JButton[] jButton = new JButton[6];
        String[] string = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"};

        this.add(jpanel);
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < jButton.length; i++) {
            while (j < 6) {
                jButton[i] = new JButton();
                jButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                jButton[i].setText(string[j]);
                jpanel.add(jButton[i]);
                jButton[i].addActionListener(listeners.get(j));
                j++;
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.List<ActionListener> listeners = List.of(
                e -> System.out.println("actionListener 1"),
                e -> System.out.println("actionListener 2"),
                e -> System.out.println("actionListener 3"),
                e -> System.out.println("actionListener 4"),
                e -> System.out.println("actionListener 5"),
                e -> System.out.println("actionListener 6")
        );
        Loop myLoop = new Loop(listeners);
        myLoop.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems from the code that to add the ActionListener in a for loop gives all the buttons the same action.

You are correct. You are creating an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that implements `ActionListener` interface. However, each `JButton` is assigned a separate instance of that class.

There is nothing wrong with assigning the same, single instance to the different `JButton`s. Inside the code of the `actionPerformed` method you can identify which `JButton` was activated by examining the `ActionEvent` parameter.

The `ActionEvent` contains a [action command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand--) string as well as the [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource--), which, in your case, is the actual `JButton` that was activated.

Personally, I would make your `Loop` class implement `ActionListener` and in the `actionPerformed` method I would determine which `JButton` was activated from the *action command*. The below code demonstrates.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Loop extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public Loop() {
        this.setSize(700, 300);
        this.setLocation(400, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6));

        JButton[] jButton = new JButton[6];
        String string[] = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"};

        this.add(jpanel);

        for (int i = 0; i < jButton.length; i++) {
            jButton[i] = new JButton(string[i]);
            jButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            jpanel.add(jButton[i]);
            jButton[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case "One":
                break;
            case "Two":
                break;
            case "Three":
                break;
            case "Four":
                break;
            case "Five":
                break;
            case "Six":
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loop myLoop = new Loop();
        myLoop.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

By default, the *action command* is assigned the text of the `JButton` but you can assign a different value via the [setActionCommand](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand-java.lang.String-) method.

Comment: I don't know, there are actions and then there are `Action` what do they mean by it gives all the buttons the same action.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.*;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Loop extends JFrame {
    
        public Loop() {
    
            final JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
            /**/         jpanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            /**/         jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6));
    
            this.add    (jpanel);
    
            Stream.of("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six")
            .forEach(text -> {
                final JButton button = new JButton(text);
                /**/          button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                /**/          button.addActionListener((e) -> {System.out.println("Button " + text + " pressed");});
                jpanel.add   (button);
            });
    
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
            this.setLocation(400, 300);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
            this.pack();
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
    
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Loop());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need some way of identifying which Button, but you can use 1 shared Listener as shown below.

Please note the use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to execute on the correct Thread.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Loop extends JFrame {

    public Loop() {

        final JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        /**/         jpanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        /**/         jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6));

        this.add    (jpanel);

        final ActionListener oneSharedListener = (e) -> System.out.println("Button " + e.getActionCommand() + " pressed");

        Stream.of("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six")
        .forEach(text -> {
            final JButton button = new JButton(text);
            /**/          button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            /**/          button.addActionListener(oneSharedListener);
            /**/          button.setActionCommand(text);
            jpanel.add   (button);
        });

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
        this.setLocation(400, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.pack();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Loop());
    }
}
```