# How to correctly implement a keypressed to allow a good connection between the keyboard of a computer and that of a software?

Tags: java

I am working on a calculator project on computer with jdk8 library. My goal is to get a working calculator from its interaction with the user through the computer keyboard. For this I was advised to use the keyPressed method from the standard library of the java in order to be able to use the keyboard keys for the operation of my software. I have successfully implemented the keypressed method. Then, I wrote a code so that when I press a key on the computer keyboard, for example b, that it activates a key on the keyboard of said calculator which will in turn display on the screen the calculator, the number it carries for example 2.

But problem, whenever I press the b key, it always returns 2b on my calculator screen.

Here is my code so that the b key on the computer can return the number 2 on my calculator screen with "screen" the name of my JTextField and "buttonTwo" the name of my Jbutton for key 2:

```
public void keyPressed ( KeyEvent e ) {

super.keyPressed(e) ;

int key = e.getKeyCode() ;

if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_B ) {

String buttonTwoText = Screen.getText() + buttonTwo.getText() ;

Screen.setText(buttonTwoText);

}

}
```

And this is what the debugger displays:
[image]

Comment: If you want it to display "2", why don't you just have `Screen.setText("2");`? The reason it's displaying "2b" is because `Screen.getText()` returns "2" and `buttonTwo.getText()` returns "b"`, so when you put those together it displays "2b".

Comment: You don't implement keyPressed. You should NOT use a KeyListener. Instead you should use `Key Bindings`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739623/how-to-add-a-shortcut-key-for-a-jbutton-in-java/33739732#33739732 for a basic example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use a key pressed event when using JTextField, because the event is already perceived by the component. You are not very clear here.

Next time publish all relevant code snippets, not just a small part of the code.

But, I guess what you want to do is to **disable editing** in the text field, so you can get better control over the text inserted by the user into the calculator display using the keyPressed() method.

Second, **you don't need one of them**:

```
Screen.getText()
```

or

```
buttonTwo.getText()
```

Make sure you are actually **disabling** the editing of the text field and insure that the **keyPressed() logic is right** (in the if section).

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_B)
        yourButton.setText(Screen.getText() + 2);
}
```