# how to select one Button in a set of buttons , like ButtonGroup for RadioButton ? in java

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton

**these are four buttons, i wanna just select one or two button!
how do i do that?**

```
public class Game {
  private JButton button1,button2,button3,button4;
  public Game(){

buttonMethod();

private void buttonMethod() {
    JButton button1 = new JButton("?");
    button1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,20));
    button1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    panel2.add(button1);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("?");
    button2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,20));
    button2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    button2.addActionListener(e->{
    button2.setText("2");
    });
    panel2.add(button2);

    JButton button3 = new JButton("?");
    button3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,20));
    button3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    button3.addActionListener(e->{
    button3.setText("3");
    });
    panel2.add(button3);

    JButton button4 = new JButton("?");
    button4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,20));
    button4.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    button4.addActionListener(e->{
    button4.setText("4");
    });
    panel2.add(button4);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Use a `JToggleButton`, or more likely `JCheckBox`.

Comment: Is your problem solved? You should respond to all suggestions so people know if the suggestion have helped or not.

Comment: @camickr thanks, i solved my problem then i used only one ActionListener after use if&else to add ActionListener  for any Buttons and finally call any buttons separate : explain more:     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI-TFbHQhtA

Comment: 1) That has nothing to do with the question you asked. 2) That is not a good solution. Yes you can share an ActionListener for multiple button, if the Action for each button is generic, but you  should NOT have if/else statements in an ActionListener. If the Action is not generic then you should use a separate ActionListener for each button. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739623/how-to-add-a-shortcut-key-for-a-jbutton-in-java/33739732#33739732 for a better example of how to create a generic ActionListener without using if/else statements.

Comment: @camickr thanks a lot, yeah you're right, but I'm beginner in java and I'm not experienced in GUI Generally.