# Java on OSX: wrong accelerator key icon in Swing menu using Netbeans GUI builder

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, menuitem, gui-builder

I created a small application using Netbeans 8.1 on OSX. It contains just two menus "file" and "edit". The purpose is to add full copy / cut / paste functionality to the edit menu later on. I want to use Netbeans GUI builder but i encounter the following problems:

*1st try:*

I created a small example with Netbeans GUI builder (Swing GUI Forms -> JDialog). I just added a menu bar to the JFrame and the a JMenuItem in the GUI builder and some code to the constructor. 
The result is:

[image]

As you can see i get a text 'meta' instead of the Apple key '⌘'.

The source code is `NewJDialogGUI.java`:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;

public class NewJDialogGUI extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    private static final int MASK
        = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();

    public NewJDialogGUI(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);

        initComponents();

        AbstractAction copyAction = new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction();
        copyAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY,KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK));


        this.jMenuItem1.setAction(copyAction);
        this.jMenuItem1.setText("Copy");
        this.jMenuItem1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");

        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");
        jMenu2.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 278, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialogGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialogGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialogGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJDialogGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                NewJDialogGUI dialog = new NewJDialogGUI(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;                 
}
```

And the `NewJDialogGUI.form`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Form version="1.3" maxVersion="1.9" type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JDialogFormInfo">
  <NonVisualComponents>
    <Menu class="javax.swing.JMenuBar" name="jMenuBar1">
      <SubComponents>
        <Menu class="javax.swing.JMenu" name="jMenu1">
          <Properties>
            <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" value="File"/>
          </Properties>
        </Menu>
        <Menu class="javax.swing.JMenu" name="jMenu2">
          <Properties>
            <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" value="Edit"/>
          </Properties>
          <SubComponents>
            <MenuItem class="javax.swing.JMenuItem" name="jMenuItem1">
              <Properties>
                <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" value="jMenuItem1"/>
              </Properties>
            </MenuItem>
          </SubComponents>
        </Menu>
      </SubComponents>
    </Menu>
  </NonVisualComponents>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="defaultCloseOperation" type="int" value="2"/>
  </Properties>
  <SyntheticProperties>
    <SyntheticProperty name="menuBar" type="java.lang.String" value="jMenuBar1"/>
    <SyntheticProperty name="formSizePolicy" type="int" value="1"/>
    <SyntheticProperty name="generateCenter" type="boolean" value="false"/>
  </SyntheticProperties>
  <AuxValues>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoResourcing" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoSetComponentName" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateFQN" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateMnemonicsCode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_i18nAutoMode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_layoutCodeTarget" type="java.lang.Integer" value="1"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_listenerGenerationStyle" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesLocal" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesModifier" type="java.lang.Integer" value="2"/>
  </AuxValues>

  <Layout>
    <DimensionLayout dim="0">
      <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
          <EmptySpace min="0" pref="400" max="32767" attributes="0"/>
      </Group>
    </DimensionLayout>
    <DimensionLayout dim="1">
      <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
          <EmptySpace min="0" pref="278" max="32767" attributes="0"/>
      </Group>
    </DimensionLayout>
  </Layout>
</Form>
```

*2nd try:*

I created another small example with Netbeans GUI builder (Swing GUI Forms -> Application sample form). The result is:

[image]

Same result like in 1st try.

*3rd try:*

Finally i created an example with Netbeans (Empty Java file) with source code slightly modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830519/5081387). The result is:

[image]

The source code is:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830519/230513
 */
public class NewEmptyGUI {

    private static final int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem();
        AbstractAction copyAction = new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction();
        copyAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY,
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK));
        menuItem.setAction(copyAction);
        menuItem.setText("Copy");
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        f.add(new JTextField(10));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                new NewEmptyGUI().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the expected result but the whole menu infrastrucure was coded manually, which is not my intention. I want to use Netbeans GUI Builder. Do you have any hints for me?

I am using JDK7 and OSX Yosemite. Look and feel is "Nimbus". I only paste the example code or 1st and 3rd try here, because it is quite a lot of code.

Comment: Thank you for a [mcve]; adding `NewJDialogGUI.form` will make it possible for others to recreate your example.

Comment: Trashgod, nice to here from you! I updated the question with the 'NewJDialogGUI.form'.

Answer (score 1):

I found solutions for the described problem.

**Solution 1 (Change look and feel):**

The code example shows how to replace the "Nimbus look and feel" in the Netbeans created code. It will also set the correct keyboard shortcuts for clipboard actions like copy & paste with Apple key '⌘' instead of the "Control-Key" automatically:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            /*
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
            */
            if ("Mac OS X".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(App_Avaprism.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(App_Avaprism.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(App_Avaprism.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(App_Avaprism.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new App_Avaprism().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want to stay with "Nimbus" things become more difficult. At first: I found no way to replace text 'meta'. At least you might want to have the clipboard shortcuts working with the Apple key '⌘'.

For your main application put the following code into the constructor:

```
int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();

InputMap im = (InputMap) UIManager.get("TextField.focusInputMap");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, MASK), DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
```

Unfortunately: If you start other modal dialogs from this main app the short cuts won't work. In this case you may try to use the KeyEventDispatcher to establish a global redirection of keystrokes for the whole app. More information about that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8485873/5081387) and [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3452231/The-KeyEventDispatcher-in-Java.htm).

Comment: Solution `1` is the default, so it's unnecessary; solution `2` is the correct way to  make `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` use the `MASK` that `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` uses by default; plus one for helpful resources.

Comment: Surprisingly i found in the Netbeans generated code `if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))` instead of the `if ("Mac OS X".equals(info.getName()))` though the GUI builder had shown "aqua l&f" in the preview and i run Netbeans under OSX. So you're right: it should be the default under OSX but in my case it wasn't. Could you check what Netbeans generates in your case as default?

Comment: Ah, I see the difference: `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` is the default with no initialization code at all, while code to set `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` (if available) is the default for generated code.